# Construct a regular expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, regular-expressions

The problem asks me to construct a regular expression for the set of strings in $\{a,b\}^*$ that have even number of $a$ and $b$.

What I have tried is $(aa)^* + (bb)^* + (aabb)^*$ but I believe it does not cover a string like $abbbaaba$.

Many thanks,

Comment: Where the $*$ in the post refers to a [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for a finite alphabet:  $A^* =\cup_{n=1}^\infty A^n$ ?

Comment: Can you be more simple please, I am quite new to this :)

Comment: I have done anything yet. You use a $*$ in your post. What does it mean? It must mean kleene star?

Comment: @Mason yes it is

Comment: Are you familiar with the procedure, given a deterministic finite state machine, to find a corresponding regular expression?  If so, that's probably the approach I'd take - first, construct the state machine with states $EE,EO,OE,OO$ and then find the corresponding regular expression.

Comment: It seems like I was not introduced to this. This problem came after 2 chapters in a book that introduces about regular expression and regular languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a complement operator $-$, we can implement Daniel Schepler's suggestion:

$$-(-(b^* ab^* ab^*)^* + -(a^* ba^* ba^*)^*).$$

Each interior parentheses says to look for two $a$'s which are separated by (any number of) $b$'s or vice versa. By putting the stars around these you allow yourself as many pairs as you want. The minus signs can be eliminated using [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) if you have access to an AND operator.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_language_theory), it's possible to take any "generalized" regular expression and turn it into a regular expression presumably by some straightforward algorithm, but I'm not seeing how to it now.